# Разработать алгоритм объявления из очереди

Tags: алгоритм, теория

Задание по "Теоретическим основам информатики". Требуется разработать алгоритм (с использованием натуральных действий и условий) объявления из очереди в определенном контексте и его конкретные представления. Под контекстом, вероятно, подразумевается что "в слове все нечетные буквы - буква А". Это является вариантом задания.

Поскольку прикрепление изображений мне не доступно в текущий момент, даю ссылку на [методичку](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/c00d69d952bf/1MU_k_kntr.djvu), в которой дано это задание (задание №1, вариант 2). Там же приведен пример реализации такого алгоритма для однобуквенного слова (стр. 12-13).

Итак, поскольку как правильно подметили, методические указания представляют собой хороший пример "шизофазии". Предлагаю такой вариант алгоритма выраженный своими словами.

1. Проверим входящее слово на "непустоту". Если слово не пустое, то к п.2, иначе п.7.
2. Проверим на соответствие символа букве А. Если так, то п.3, иначе п.7.
3. Будем считать данный символ началом слова. Перейдем к п.4
4. Проверим, является ли символ концом слова. Если так, то п.5, иначе п.8.
5. Прекращаем рассмотрение данной буквы данного слова. Перейдем к п.6
6. Конец алгоритма.
7. Перейдем к следующей букве входного слова. Перейдем к п.2
8. Перейдем к следующей букве входного слова. Перейдем к п.9
9. Проверим, является ли выбранный символ концом слова. Если так, то к п.5, иначе 10.
10. Перейдем к следующей букве входного слова. Перейдем к п.11
11. Проверим на соответствие букве А. Если так, то п.4, иначе п.7

**Обновление**

Основная проблема заключается в применении т.н. натуральный действий и условий. Подобных заданий я не встречал в сети, чтобы сделать по образу и подобию.
Понятно, что в начале алгоритма требуется проверить входное слово на условие непустоты. Затем, как мне кажется, следует проверить на условие одинаковости символа, и только затем сделать пометку, что данный символ является началом слова. Здесь все верно?

Comment: @szharov, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Основная проблема заключается в применении т.н. натуральный действий и условий. Подобных заданий я не встречал в сети, чтобы сделать по образу и подобию.
Понятно, что в начале алгоритма требуется проверить входное слово на условие непустоты. Затем, как мне кажется, следует проверить на условие одинаковости символа, и только затем сделать пометку, что данный символ является началом слова. Здесь все верно?

Comment: @szharov, да, не повезло Вам. 

Эта методичка просто какой-то бред с доморощенной терминологией, прорываться через который (разбираться, что именно имеют в виду "преподаватели") совершенно не хочется.

Comment: Понимаю Ваше удивление. А мне не хочется, а приходится. К сожалению, там даже автор не указан.
Хорошо, а если попробовать абстрагироваться от доморощенных терминов, и просто своими словами описать алгоритм? Я попробую отредактировать текст вопроса, чтобы рассказать свое представление об алгоритме.

Comment: @szharov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

По идее, можно и короче.

1. Если мы находимся в конце слова, алгоритм завершается с положительным ответом.
2. Если текущая буква не `A`, алгоритм завершается с отрицательным ответом.
3. Перейти к следующей букве.
4. Если мы после перехода находимся в конце слова, алгоритм завершается с положительным ответом.
5. Перейти к следующей букве и вернуться в пункт 1.

(Я ориентируюсь на ваш алгоритм как на образец.)

Comment: Хорошо, кажется, мысль я понял, но разве это корректно по отношению к очереди? Конечно, мы можем пробежаться до некоторого символа и проверить является ли он концом слова,  но сказать, что это будет являться корректным искомым словом, мы не можем.

Comment: @szharov: Идея в том, что если мы _добежали_, то всё уже хорошо. Если строка «неправильная», то мы обязательно встретили бы проблемы по дороге и завершили алгоритм досрочно (в пункте 2).